# Receiving a JSON object from Android to a PHP Webservice

Tags: php, android, json

I have tried looking at several links but I cannot seem to get it right. I am trying to send a JSON object from my android application which contains 'username' and 'password'. But I am not sure if this data is actually been sent to the web-service. I am not too sure if I got the code right for reading JSON object in the php script.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    String userID = "";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURI);
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,10000);

    try {

        jsonObject.put("username", username);
        jsonObject.put("password", password);

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        stringEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            userID = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            Log.i("Read from server", userID);
         }

    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Login_Issue", e.toString());
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Here is the beginning of the PHP script.

```
<?php

include('dbconnect.php'); 

$tablename = 'users';

 //username and password sent from android
$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

 .....
 ?>
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here please? I cannot seem to figure out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a list of `NameValuePairs` to your `HttpPost` object, so you know the keys you can use to retrieve the data in your PHP script. See the example code snippets below.

The Java:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

The PHP:

```
$username = $_POST['username']
$password = $_POST['password']
```

Comment: Thanks. It did the trick. Could you tell me the difference between $_REQUEST and $_POST please? Thank you

Comment: $_REQUEST is for all type of methods including get and post.  $_POST is for only post methods